# k8s Cluster role create cant get the right permissions

Tags: kubernetes

create a Cluster role and ClusterRoleBinding for see pods logs but i cant get access

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: read-permissions
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  - services
  - configmaps
  - pods
  - deployments
  - endpoints
  verbs:
  - list
  - get
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: read-permissions-binding
  namespace: scourge
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: system:read-logs
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: read-permissions
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

```
kubectl auth can-i get pod --as="user"  --as-group=read-pod 

Warning: the server doesn't have a resource type 'pod'
Error from server (Forbidden): selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden:   
User "idow" cannot create resource "selfsubjectaccessreviews"   
in API group "authorization.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
```

if i ran this command with another group it succeed

Comment: Are u using the same namespace? If you add `--all-namespaces, what are the results?

Comment: shouldnt it be "read-logs" instead of "read-pod" in `kubectl auth can-i get pod --as="user"  --as-group=read-pod`